# Why is my CSS broken?

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/ahlborg3000/zbb9szkq/

I´m making my own tutorial website to learn web dev but the CSS started breaking on me. Now only some text editing works. W3C CSS Validator and CSS Lint only point to a parsing error on line 113:

Edit: Parsing Errors:   Expected COLON at line 113, col 3.

Edit: Line 90:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Joti One';
```

Line 113:

```
p {
    color: lime;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

But why have my code stopped working one by one? Please help.

Edit: delinear caugt the missing curly bracket the should have followed on line 92 and caused all following code to fail. Thanks!

Comment: Which one is line 113? Please post more code and the complete error message!

Comment: Please have a look into [ask] and improve your question to avoid further downvotes and to get a useful answer. And welcome to SO!

Comment: You missed the closing curly brace for the `body` section in the lines above `p {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't closing this style:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Joti One';
```

Which causes everything after that to fail. Fixing that also results in the following validation issues:

```
290 .p3 Value Error : border-top-style Too many values or values are not recognized : dotted 5px lime
291 .p3 Value Error : border-right-style Too many values or values are not recognized : dashed 7px #ff0000
292 .p3 Value Error : border-bottom-style Too many values or values are not recognized : solid 7px rgb(255, 0, 0)
293 .p3 Value Error : border-left-style Too many values or values are not recognized : double 5px lime
303 html    Value Error : font-family Missing a semicolon before the property name background-color
```

The border issues are caused because you're passing non-`border-style` values to the `border-style` property, you should just be using `border-top`, `border-right`, etc (unless you're specifically just trying to change the style here, in which case you should just pass the dotted, dashed, etc values and not the width and colour).

Finally, I don't think `background-clip: text;` is currently supported unprefixed (at least the validator complains about it). It shouldn't affect the rest of the CSS being displayed but worth noting.